# How do I display an image over a table cell that's larger than the cell?

Tags: html, css, layout

I've got a `TABLE` that's actually being used for its intended purpose, to display a grid.  The cells are fixed-size cells, with both the width and the height of each cell being constant and defined in CSS.

I can put text and images into the cells easily enough, as long as they fit.  But if I try to put an image that's larger than the cell into a `TD`, it ends up stretching the cell, and either its entire column or its entire row (or both) depending on which dimension(s) are too big.

I need the table to remain fixed-size, but I also need an image positioned at a specific cell, which is larger than the cell.  How should I go about setting this effect up?

To give a simple example:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   | X |   |
+---+---+---+
|   | X |   |
+---+---+---+
```

Imagine the image is exactly as wide and twice as high as one cell.  What do I need to do to make it cover two vertical cells perfectly?

Comment: please place your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: If I had anything resembling working code, I wouldn't have to ask this. :P

Comment: I didn't told you to place working code.. I just told about paste what you have tried.... :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `max-width` and `max-height` properties to `100%`, so that the image doesn't exceed the cell. Fiddle coming on the way! :)

### HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://windows7supportnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Windows-vista-help-1.jpg" class="normal" /></td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td><img src="http://windows7supportnow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Windows-vista-help-1.jpg" class="fullsize" /></td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="normal" src="http://edibleapple.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/silver-apple-logo.png" /></td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("normal");
    });
});​
```

### CSS

```
td, td img.normal, img.fullsize.normal {height: 100px; max-height: 100px; width: 100px; max-width: 100px;}
td {position: relative;}
img.fullsize {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 100; height: auto; max-height: auto; width: auto; max-width: auto;}​
```

### Preview & Demo

[image: Table]

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4f9K5/1/

Comment: I don't want the image to "not exceed the cell" if that means clipping or truncation; I want it to draw at full size, but not *stretch* the cell.  I figure this probably involves not actually putting the `IMG` tag inside of the `TD`, but doing something more complicated instead. I just don't quite know what that more complicated thing is.

Comment: Okay, will address both the issues! :)

Comment: You can also think of giving a `click` event, which resizes the image to its original size, and upon clicking it again, will resize it back to normal. Will update that code in fiddle as well as in teh answer and update it! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
<style>td{ width:100px; vertical-align:top;  height:100px; border:solid 1px;}
img{position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}</style><script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>    <body>

<table>
<tr><td><div style="position:relative;"><img src="planet.png"></div></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
    </html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bRyCw/4/